# Container for template classes?

Tags: c++, oop

I have a template class defined as follows:

```
template <class T>
class AsynStep
{
public:
    AsynStep(std::function<T()> worker) : Worker(worker) {}
    void Run() { Worker(); }
protected:
    std::function<T()> Worker;
}
```

(It is a simplified view, in the real life I use a result of Worker() somehow).

The AsynStep objects are created as follows:

```
auto step1 = new AsynStep<int>(Func1);
auto step2 = new AsynStep<std::string>(Func2);
```

(Many other custom types are possible here).

Now I would like to put step1 and step2 together into a container (like std::vector) to be able to do something like this:

```
for (auto &step : Steps)
{
      step->Run();
}
```

How can I create a such container?

I tried some casts but without any success :(

Comment: Inherit them from a common non-template base, make `Run` a virtual function, use `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<BaseClass>> as a container.

Comment: How would you use that container, if each function returns a different type?

Comment: If your set of supported types is limited, you can also use `std::variant` of `std::function`s. Simplified demo: https://godbolt.org/z/3arfWhE4Y.

Comment: > How would you use that container, if each function returns a different type?

In the real life, the result is passed to another function std::function<bool(T)> validator and I use the bool result of it.

Comment: > If your set of supported types is limited

No, it is not limited, I cannot use std::variant

Comment: You are doing something strange. `Worker` returns a value of type `T`, but `AsynStep::Run()` discards returned value. This is fishy. For me question suffers from [XY problem](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). I do not know what is your actual goal is, but I'm pretty sure it can be done better then this `AsynStep` class.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Does the following work?

```c++
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

class Base {
    public:
        virtual void Run() = 0;
};

template <class T>
class AsynStep: public Base {
    public:
        explicit AsynStep(std::function<T()> worker) : Worker(std::move(worker)) {}
        void Run() override { Worker(); }
    protected:
        std::function<T()> Worker;
};

int main() {

    auto step1 = new AsynStep<int>([]() { return 2; });
    auto step2 = new AsynStep<std::string>([]() { return "Hello!"; });
    std::vector<Base*> steps = {step1, step2};
    for (auto &step: steps) {
        step->Run();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please [do not use bits/stdc++.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h).

Comment: `Base` should have a virtual destructor. `std::unique_ptr<Base>` as opposed to `Base*` will make life easier.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Updated the header files.

Comment: Base MUST have a virtual destructor!

Comment: And to avoid memory leaks use `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>>`

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Formally, no virtual destructor is required as long as he never deletes the object:-). If he's using `new`, I would definitely recommend it -- I can think of special cases where this might not be necessary, but not where the object definition is globally accessible. But the real question here is: why use dynamic allocation at all. Just declare static instances, and initialize the vector with their address (`&step1, &step2`).

Comment: Thanks, Abhishek bansal, you code works correctly (the idea was proposed by HolyBlackCat in the first comment though). In the real code I'll certainly use virtual destructor in the base class and std::unique_ptr in allocator.

Comment: @PepijnKramer I'm not sure I agree -- initialization of the vector becomes really difficult with `std::unique_ptr`.